# Is Peano's Axioms redundant?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What's the purpose of defining **five** Peano's Axioms if we can just define the natural numbers as (by mathematical induction):

> Define $0\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> If $x\in\mathbb{N}$, define $(x+1)\in\mathbb{N}$

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: In that case $\mathbb{N}$ could be finite, for example $\mathbb{Z}/(10)$, the integers modulo $10$.

Comment: You are assuming there is some “number”, e.g. $0$, and there is a binary operation $+$. For pedagogical (or other) reasons, Peano arithmetic is usually worked out in a context without mathematical induction, $0$, $\in$, etc. If this is still confusing, an introductory text on first order logic might help.

Comment: For clarity, we denote the *successor* of $x$ with $s(x)$ (or $x'$, and not with $x+1$); having said that, we have to specify that equal numbers have equal successors and that $0$ is not a successor. See [Landau](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Foundations_of_Analysis/DvIJBAAAQBAJ).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398144/the-uniqueness-of-the-successor-peanos-axioms)

Answer (score 2):

Insofar as you cannot deduce the remaining axioms from the two that you have provided, the answer is no - they are not redundant. If there is no  axiom asserting that zero is not the successor of any number, then we can define the natural numbers as the set $\{0\}$ endowed with the successor operation that is trivially given by $s(0) = 0$. Moreover, you could define $\mathbb{N}$ to be a finite set if there is no axiom stating that the successor function is one-to-one. And since your question itself makes an appeal to the principle of mathematical induction, we probably don't want to discard that axiom either!